# What does {ggdist}'s stat_interval levels calculate (I thought it was confidence intervals but they're not correct)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, confidence-interval

I'm using `ggdist` (which is awesome) to show variability within a sample. I have a series of means, SDs, and std.errors and I want to use the `stat_interval()` function to show the 50%, 80%, 90%, and 95% confidence intervals of these samples. It seems that they're calculating something different because the intervals being plotted are very different to when I calculate confidence intervals manually. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong / what the function is doing?

The 95% CI of Sample 1 in the attached plot should be from 39.38 - 39.62 but it's being plotted much larger (nearly 38.5 - 40.5, see image).

Reprex ↓

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)

 data <- tibble::tribble(
            ~n,          ~mean,     ~SD,       ~se,
           "Sample 1",    39.5,     0.5,    0.0625,
           "Sample 2",    39.4,     0.6,    0.0750
           )

 data |>
   ggplot(aes(xdist = dist_normal(mean, SD),  y = fct_rev(factor(n)))) +
            stat_interval(.width = c(.5, .8, .9, .95), position = "dodge")
```

[image: stat_interval_plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ranges being plotted are simply the quantiles, not confidence intervals. e.g.:

```
> quantile(rnorm(10000, 39.5, 0.5), c(0.025, 0.975 ))
    2.5%    97.5% 
38.49979 40.46578
```

For confidence intervals, I think you are looking for Students T. e.g.:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(xdist = distributional::dist_student_t( 63, mean, se),  y = fct_rev(factor(n)))) +
  stat_interval(.width = c(.5, .8, .9, .95), position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Ah yep. This looks to be what's happening. Thanks Devin! Do you know how to get confidence intervals using `stat_interval()`?

Comment: For some history: ggdist's default is quantile intervals, which are often used to make credible intervals from posterior distributions in Bayesian stats (the original use case for ggdist, though it has since been expanded other use cases like frequentist vis). Applied to a data sample (or a Normal(mean, sd) dist), quantile intervals are not inferential intervals like CIs. @Devin's suggestion to instead pass dist_student_t the degrees of freedom, mean, and standard error (not SD) is a good one, and yields t-based CIs. See also: https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/articles/freq-uncertainty-vis.html